# How to show and hide DIV based on URL. in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I have two URL's

```
url 1 = www.xyz.co.uk/asd.qmd
url 2 = www.xyz.co.uk/asd.qmd?getstep=4#
```

I want to show a div(left)  when  PAGE URL is **www.xyz.co.uk/asd.qmd?getstep=4#**

In the page form.php I wrote the following code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var locate = window.location;

        if (locate=="http://localhost/school/form.php") {
            $('#left').hide();
        } else {
            $('#left').show();
        }
    });
</script>

<body  onload="function()">
    <div id="left">
        aasdsasdfdsgfg
    </div>
</body>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: ok what about php condition ... this is stupid...

Answer (score 2):

Just make php condition

```
<?php
if($_GET['getstep']){

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#left').toggle(window.location.href !== "http://localhost/school/form.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a show/hide function the proper javascript way. What you are doing at first with the (I assume) jQuery is beyond me - just declare a simple function containing the code you already have to show/hide and attach it to the onload-event.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the div when the query string is empty, you could use the `search` property of the `window.location` object:

```
$(function(){
      if (window.location.search === "") {
            $('#left').hide();
      } else {
            $('#left').show();
      }
 });
```

Anything more complicated (i.e. a different div for each page value) and I recommend you look at [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `href` property of the `window.location` object.

```js
var locate = window.location.href,
  myElement = $('#left');
locate == "http://localhost/school/form.php" 
  ? myElement.show() 
  : myElement.hide();
```